# Continuous bijection between the hawaiian earring and the wedge of circles

Tags: general-topology, continuity

There are many questions about $H$ (the hawaiian earring) and $W$ (the countably infinite wedge of circles) not being homeomorphic, and that's fine. My question is about a continuous bijection between them. Define $W$ as the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}_+ \times S^1$, where $0$ and $-1$ are identified on every circle, and $H$ as the union of circles $C_n$ of radius $1\over n$ centered at $(\frac1n, 0)$. The map $C_n \leftrightarrow (\frac1n, S^1)$ is a bijection (correct me if I'm wrong), but I can't get the continuity straight. I realize that $W$ gets the quotient topology and $H$ the subspace topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but how do the open sets in the respective topologies actually look? Is the above map a good way to start, and if so, how do I show that the preimage of an open set in $H$ is open in $W$ (or vice versa)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $W\to H$ is continuous but not $H\to W$. The continuity of $W\to H$ comes from the universal property of quotient maps.

Comment: So this is a bijection from the infinite wedge of circles to the Hawaiian earring, and not vise versa.

Comment: Think of a convenient neighborhood basis for the origin in the Hawaiian earring. Look at what each preimage looks like.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger i don't understand your comment. Bijections are invertible. If $f:X\to Y$ is a bijection then $g: Y \to X$ is a bijection, where $g=f^{-1}$, no?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Yes, but the inverse of a continuous bijection need not be continuous. He wants a continuous bijection from the infinite wedge of circles to the Hawaiian earring, not a continuous bijection from the Hawaiian earring to the infinite wedge of circles.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger i'm aware of that fact but the comment i replied to did not mention continuity at all...but i suppose you were implicitly....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why is $H \to W$ not continuous?